# PostgreSQL and Hibernate JPA not working

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm trying to use JPA in Wildfly (which uses Hibernate) with PostgreSQL. I turned on hibernate.show_sql so I can execute the same query in PgAdmin III.
The query is this one (**EDIT:** issuemanager_sch is the schema. Without it even in PgAdmin the query fails with "relation does not exist" error):

```
select issuetypet0_.id_issue_type as id_issue1_3_, issuetypet0_.name as name2_3_ from issuemanager_sch.issue_type issuetypet0_
```

When executed by Hibernate this is showed in both PostgreSQL log and Wildfly log :

```
relation "issuemanager_sch.issue_type" does not exist character 87
```

However, when I copy (to grant I'm executing the exact same query), paste and run the query in PgAdmin III it's executed normally and I get the results.

What could possibly be wrong with my configurations? (I tried with both quoted and unquoted queries and the results are the same: fails for Hibernate, works in PgAdmin III)

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="PersistenceManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:/datasources/issuemanager_pg</non-jta-data-source>

        <class>com.im.issuerepository.domain.IssueTO</class>
        <class>com.im.issuerepository.domain.IssueTypeTO</class>
        <class>com.im.userrepository.domain.UserTO</class>
        <class>com.im.userrepository.domain.GroupTO</class>
        <class>com.im.userrepository.domain.RoleTO</class>

        <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="issuemanager_sch"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**EDIT:** issue_type table:

```
CREATE TABLE issuemanager_sch.issue_type
(
  id_issue_type bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('issuemanager_sch.issue_type_seq'::regclass),
  name text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_ISSUE_TYPE" PRIMARY KEY (id_issue_type)
)
```

**EDIT:** IssueTypeTO mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "issue_type")
public class IssueTypeTO implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_issue_type")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "issue_type_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "issue_type_seq", sequenceName = "issue_type_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long idIssueType;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 45)
    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Could you post your mappings and your involved tables?

Comment: @Genzotto I've updated the question with the data you've requested =)
Thanks

Comment: And which is the query you are executing?

Comment: @Genzotto The one in the first code block.

Comment: I meant your source code query, not the sql query hibernate builds

Comment: @Genzotto I didn't get what you want :/

I'm executing on PgAdmin III the exact same query Hibernate builds and it works there, but it doesn't on my application.

Comment: I meant the query you wrote on your source code, your HQL query

Comment: @Genzotto I didn't write any queries in HQL or JPQL. It's a common SELECT query built by Hibernate. I'm trying to stick with pure JPA, using EntityManager instead of Hibernate Session. I just forgot to mention I'm using Spring Data JPA (but in a CDI environment). This query is generated by the findAll() defined [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#findAll()).

Comment: @Genzotto Spring Data JPA uses interfaces and generate the implementation at runtime. But in this case, as it is a default method, I think they use a query template like
`select {entity.fields} from {entity.table}`